# The menu of webpage in smartphone mode invade others div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem on this page with TwitterBootstrap CSS menu in smartphone mode :

http://stackoverflow.kecoo.com/app_dev.php/login

the div which contains the menu do not resize its height and div under the menu was invaded by the menu when we click on "Menu" div.

I don't found solution, if someone can help me, that will be great.

Best regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in smartphone.css, around line 1429, you need to set
height to auto for container-sum because the rule in desktop.css is too strong

```
body.login .main-container header #navbar .container-sum { height: auto; }
```

or you could add you own fix.css and wrap this rule inside

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
}
```